# How to find the latest date in nested array of objects (MongoDB)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, react-native

I am trying to find the latest "order" in "orders" array in the whole collection (Not only in the one object).

Data:

```
[
  {
    _id: 1,
    orders: [
      {
        title: 'Burger',
        date: {
          $date: '2021-07-18T13:12:08.717Z',
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    _id: 2,
    orders: [
      {
        title: 'Salad',
        date: {
          $date: '2021-07-18T13:35:01.586Z',
        },
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

Code:

```
  var restaurant = await Restaurant.findOne({
    'orders.date': 1,
  });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather simple:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $project: { latest_order: { $max: "$orders.date" } } }
])
```

If you like to get the full order use this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      latest_order: {
        $first: {
          $filter: {
            input: "$orders",
            cond: { $eq: [ "$$this.date", { $max: "$orders.date" } ] }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { $sort: { "latest_order.date": 1 } },
  { $limit: 1 }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/LwkgKAoTckV)

Answer (score 1):

You have to use aggregation for that

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $unwind: "$orders" },
  { $sort: {  "orders.date": -1 } },
  { $limit: 1 },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$_id",
      "orders": { "$first": "$orders" }
    }
  }
])
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/blyDa6pBV_v)**

Comment: Using `$unwind` and afterwards `$group": { _id: "$_id" ...` is often an overkill.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I accept, but he mentioned the latest object within whole collection... is that possible to to get without unwind?

Comment: Yes, see my solution. Or you can use a final `$group` as last stage. The `$unwind` you can avoid.